# How can I add class to every quote element?

Tags: themes, css, hooks, block-editor, the-content

How can I edit defualt class of quote element?
Can I use some kind of hook in the_content to add class to any other element??

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.